# Changing particle colours using objects

Tags: particles, color

I am trying to make particles change colour when flowing through an objects space.

Basically I would like any particle that flows into the area occupied by the cube (or any shape) to change to a specified colour.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I know ... *Bake* liquid sim, select *Domain* and export as **Alembic** (.abc) just enable *Selected Only* and *Particle System* under properties ... import back into .blend file.

[image]

Add *Geometry Nodes* modifier and create a node tree to generate *IcoSphere* on points and use **Geometry Proximity** node as factor for material node tree ... for that there is the *Store Named Attribute* node (I name it "color" but you can type what ever you want) ... just for example purpose I used Torus object as object to be the factor.

[image]
[image]

Setup this shader ... type into Attribute node "color" (or what ever you typed into *Store Named Attribute* node ...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Note: for simple objects like rectangles you can set procedural shared directly for your particle system (without all this middle steps), but you asked for any type of shape :)